# can't run asterisk, no /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

Tags: asterisk

i'm trying to install asterisk on my server, I follow to [this sample](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-asterisk-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
But, in the end of installation, when I call

```
sudo asterisk -vvvr
```

it shows me

```
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
```

I check systemctl, and found this message -

```
    root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01:/usr/src/asterisk-15.7.2# systemctl status asterisk
● asterisk.service - LSB: Asterisk PBX
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/asterisk; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-03-23 15:55:45 UTC; 36min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 1152)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/asterisk.service

Mar 23 15:55:45 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Asterisk PBX...
Mar 23 15:55:45 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 asterisk[23881]:  * Starting Asterisk PBX: asterisk
Mar 23 15:55:45 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 asterisk[23881]: Unable to open specified master config file '/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf', using built-in defaults
Mar 23 15:55:45 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 asterisk[23881]:    ...done.
Mar 23 15:55:45 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Asterisk PBX.
```

Absolutely have no idea where I should search for this configuration file, or why it did not appear. Installed asterisk version - asterisk-15.7.2
Also try with latest version, and same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed step

```
make samples
```

So now asterisk have no configs and you have create it.